# Java: Looping issue within my file reading program

Tags: java, eclipse

I've only been coding for a couple months so I'm still fairly new.
I'm writing a program using Java in Eclipse IDE that reads a file containing data about the changing popularity of various baby names over time and displays the data about a particular name (which is entered via keyboard by the user). Each line of the file stores a name followed by integers representing the name's popularity in each decade: 1900, 1910, 1920, and so on. My program prompts the user for a name, searchs the file for that name, and displays the data for that name from the file to the screen.

Example of data from txt file:  Sam 58 69 99 131 168 236 278 380 467 408 466

Example of what should be displayed on screen:

```
 Statistics on name "Sam"
 1900: 58
 1910: 69
 1920: 99
 1930: 131
 ...
```

This is my program:

```
public class fileAndExceptionHanding {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null; 
        Scanner inFS = null; 
        String userName = ""; 
        String fileName = ""; 
        File file = new File("names.txt");
        List<Integer> numNamesOfYear = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        boolean repeatSearch = true;
        boolean repeatNameSearch = true;
        int startingYear = 1900; 
        int yearCounter = startingYear;
        char userKey; 
        fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("names.txt"); 
        inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        System.out.println("This program allows you to search through the data from the Social 
        Security Administration to see how popular a particular name has been since 1900.");

        do {
        System.out.println("Name? ");
        userName = keyboard.next();
        do {
            while (!(fileName.equals(userName)) && inFS.hasNextLine()) {
                fileName = inFS.next();
        }
        if (!(fileName.equals(userName))) {
                System.out.println("Error! Name was not found. Please enter another name for our 
                system to search.");
                userName = keyboard.next();
                repeatNameSearch = true;
            }
            else {
                repeatNameSearch = false;
            }
            
            
            } while (repeatNameSearch);
                
            while (inFS.hasNextInt()) {
                numNamesOfYear.add(inFS.nextInt());
            }
            System.out.println("Statistics on name " + "\"" + userName + "\"");
            yearCounter = startingYear;

            for (int i = 0; i < numNamesOfYear.size(); ++i) {
                System.out.println("     " + yearCounter + ": " + numNamesOfYear.get(i));
                yearCounter += 10; 
            }
            numNamesOfYear.clear();
            System.out.println("If you would like to search another name for popularity data, 
            please enter \"y\" to continue.");
            System.out.println("If you wish to exit, please press any other key.");
            userKey = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            
            if (!(userKey == 'y' || userKey == 'Y')) {
                repeatSearch = false;
            }
            
            }while (repeatSearch);
    fileByteStream.close(); // Closing file and input stream.
    keyboard.close(); // Closing keyboard scanner.
    inFS.close(); // Closing file scanner.
    }

}
```

My program is running perfectly at first until the prompt for the user to enter "y" to continue or any other key to exit. When I enter "Y/y" and enter another name to search, my program doesn't repeat the name search and instead displays my "error invalid name, please enter a different name to search" message even though the name I entered is valid and inside the txt file.
Example of another name and data within the txt file that I tried to repeat search for:
Abbey 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 537 451 428

```
If you would like to search another name for popularity data, please enter "y"
to continue.
If you wish to exit, please press any other key.
y
Name? 
Abbey
Error! Name was not found. Please enter another name for our system to search.
```

Entering "Sam" gives me correct data but if I press y to repeat loop and enter "Sam" again, it prints the following (Skips year data output):

```
This program allows you to search through the data from the Social Security Administration to see how popular a particular name has been since 1900.
Name? 
Sam
Statistics on name "Sam"
1900: 58
1910: 69
1920: 99
1930: 131
1940: 168
1950: 236
1960: 278
1970: 380
1980: 467
1990: 408
2000: 466
If you would like to search another name for popularity data, please enter "y"
to continue.
If you wish to exit, please press any other key.
y
Name? 
Sam
Statistics on name "Sam"
If you would like to search another name for popularity data, please enter "y"
to continue.
If you wish to exit, please press any other key.
```

I assume the problem lies somewhere within my loops, however it's proving difficult for me to find.
Any help or advice on where my looping problem lies would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to use an IDE debugger, set breakpoints, and step through the program?  That is the place to start with problems like these, and is a valuable (and required) skill for any developer.

Comment: At a quick glance you appear to be reading through the file and *not* breaking when the name is found. If so, that's wrong. Note 'fileName' in your code is very confusing. It should be something more like `nameFromFile` or better `personNameFromFile`. Don't be afraid to lengthen your variable names if it makes your code more self-documenting

Comment: off topic:  By the way, you can set a `boolean` variable with a logical expression:  `repeatSearch = userKey == 'Y' || userKey == 'y';` .

Comment: This test should give you an idea of where the problem is:  First, run the program and enter several names, in alphabetical order. Exit the program, and then rerun the program and enter the same names in reverse alphabetical order. Example: Adam, David, James, Joseph, Mary, Stephen. Then try Stephen, Mary, Joseph.

Comment: Someone else got the same assignment. That question does have answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74592444/is-there-way-a-reset-a-scanner-in-java#comment131667557_74592444